# StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing EVAL

Tags: asp.net, session, redis

I am using Redis cache for storing session from asp.net core application, but at some point, an exception has occurred as follow

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 2, queue: 16, qu: 0, qs: 15, qc: 1, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 501, ar: 0, clientName: , serverEndpoint: 104.211.115.54:6379, keyHashSlot: 4394 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)    at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2120    at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 81    at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate(String script, RedisKey[] keys, RedisValue[] values, CommandFlags flags) in c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line 1052    at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisExtensions.HashMemberGet(IDatabase cache, String key, String[] members)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache.GetAndRefresh(String key, Boolean getData)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession.Load()
```

I have added extra connection properties in connetionstring`connectTimeout=10000,syncTimeout=2000,connectRetry=3`

What additional setting required for resolve this exception?